# running a csv input API and connecting to a zoomable sunburst API

Tags: html, api, visualization

I hope you are having a nice day.

I am trying to use this CSV input API -- https://github.com/MounirMesselmeni/html-fileapi -- to populate the data array in this zoomable sunburst API:https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/.

Currently, I am able to load in the CSV to the API, and the contents will show on the screen. However, the data is not connecting to the Data Visualization API Script. I am very confused as to why it is not.

See the picture here -- [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQeY2.png

Currently, the computer is saying there is a "Unexpected end of input" at the final  which the Data visualization API is contained within.

It won't even reach the console.log("hello") statement within the script :,(

The code looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>CSV to Zoomable Sunburs</title>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <form class="form-horizontal well">
            <legend>
                <h3>
                    <div id="title">HTML5 File API</div>
                </h3>
            </legend>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="csvFileInput"> <strong>CSV File:</strong>
                </label>
                <input type="file" id="csvFileInput" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" accept=".csv">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="output">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id='myDiv'>
        <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="read-csv.js"></script>

</body>


<script>
    lines = FileReader.readAsText(Blob|File, opt_encoding);
    console.log("hello");
    pieces = []; 
    tempData = [];
```

(also just to note tempData should hold all of the pieces of the data and then pieces will be used to populate the data array later more easily)

```
    while (typeof lines[0] !== "undefined") {

        var line = lines.shift();
        var split = line.split(',');

        console.log("this is the line: " + line);
        console.log("this is the split: " + split);

        tempData.push(split);
        document.querySelector("#content").innerHTML += split[0] + "<br/>";
    }

    // iterate through the temp data file
    for (let i = 0; i < tempData.length; i += 1) {
        const currentKey = tempData[i];
        const currItem = calendarE[currentKey];

        if (i == 0) { // type
            pieces[0] = tempData[0];
        }
```

which then populates the data array as such:

```
        var data = [{
            type: pieces[0],

            labels: pieces[1],
            parents: pieces[2],

            outsidetextfont: { size: pieces[3], color: pieces[4], },
            leaf: { opacity: pieces[5], },
            marker: { line: { width: pieces[6], } },
        }];
```

and then ends as such:

```
    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

</script>

</html>
```

Any help as to why I am not getting any console.log statements from inside the data visualization script would be AWESOME thank you so so much!!